# PHP parse array to add css

Tags: php, parsing, foreach

I have the following code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$output_items[] = $row["title"]; } // while

print(implode("\n", $output_items));
```

Which does what it says and splits the array with a new line for each item.

But how do I do the same and allow formatting with i.e. I basically want to say

```
foreach of the $output_items echo "<div class=whatever>$output_items</div> etc etc
```

Tearing my hair out with this!

Many thanks for all help

Darren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple, to make it easier to read I'd do something like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<div class="whatever">';
    echo $row["title"];
    echo '</div>' . "\n";
} // while
```

Although you could still do this with your original code pretty easily:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$output_items[] = '<div class="whatever">' . $row["title"] . '</div>'; } // while

print(implode("\n", $output_items));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach ($output_items as $oi){
    echo "<div class=whatever>$oi</div>";
}
```

doesn't work? or i did not get what you are searching for

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `implode()` them all with line breaks, use string interpolation to add them together:

```
$out_string = "";

// Loop over your array $output_items and wrap each in <div />
// while appending each to a single output string.
foreach ($output_items as $item) {
  $out_string .= "<div class='whatever'>$item</div>\n";
}

echo $out_string;
```